# x64 C# Application does not display OpenFileDialog once the exe is signed with SignTool

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, signtool

My C# application seems to freeze when i try launching the OpenFileDialog() for Import functionality. This has started happening since I've signed the exe with SignTool. With reference to, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/cross-certificates-for-kernel-mode-code-signing , I have tried adding cross-certificate for the application but still the OpenFileDialog() dialog does not show up, which looks like the application is frozen. Also, the application works fine if i check "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox, but I cannot do that for my 64 bit application.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: That's a link for signing kernel mode binaries, I don't think thats what your C# application is ...

Comment: Yes, i tried cross certification mode, since the functionality started blocking due to company signing. So, i thought of adding microsoft signature to the exe. I might be completely wrong here, though.